# Validate duplicate input based on formArray in Angular by rxweb

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

How to validate duplicate `OwnerId` in `formArray`. I am trying install this `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators` but it not working. This my demo code [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9uufry?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 d-flex" [formGroupName]="i"
      *ngFor="let driver of nameDriverControl.controls; let i=index">
      <label>{{i+1}}.Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name{{i}}"  formControlName="name" ><br/>
      <label>{{i+1}}.Owner Id</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ownerId" name="ownerId{{i}}" inputmode="numeric" dashFormat formControlName="ownerId" maxLength="14">
      <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
        <div class="form-group mb-0" *ngIf="i !== 0">

          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeDriver(i)">
      Delete
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2">

          <button *ngIf="i >= 0 && i < 1" type="button" [hidden]="nameDriver.length > 3" (click)="addDriver()" class="btn btn-primary">
      Add
    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Component**

```
createDriver () {
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      ownerId: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    })
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577133/validation-to-prevent-duplicate-form-values-in-angular-forms/58582165#58582165

Comment: I checked your `Stackblitz` link but it seems that you don't use `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators` right?

Comment: yes is a "simple" custom validators

Comment: I've used `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators` but it not working as what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `unique` validator of last version of `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators`  (`2.1.3`).

After installation you need to import `@rxweb` like this:

```
import { RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';
```

Then in your `createDriver` methods add `unique` validator for `ownerId` like this:

```
createDriver () {
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      ownerId: new FormControl("", RxwebValidators.unique(
        { message: 'You must enter a unique OwnerId' }
      ))
    })
}
```

And in your HTML template you can add error message like this:

```
<small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="driver.controls.ownerId.errors">{{driver.controls.ownerId.errors.unique.message}}<br/></small>
```

Here is working sample that I've created for you: [StackBlitzLink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxweb-reactive-form-validator-angular-5fuveh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

And the result:

[image]

See [this](https://docs.rxweb.io/form-validations/unique/validators) for more information about `unique` validtion.